# react_component in twig generate : "ReferenceError: window is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, symfony, webpack, symfony4, react-on-rails

I am currently experiencing a problem with the reactJs + Symfony 4.3 + WebPack stack. I have error "ReferenceError: window is not defined"
Below is my code for package.jon, composer.json, webpack Config, controller symfony

Here is My Composer.Json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "limenius/react-bundle": "^3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/asset": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/translation": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.3.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.6",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.3.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.3.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is My Package.Json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.27.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress",
        "webpack-serverside": "encore dev --config webpack.config.serverside.js --watch"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "global": "^4.4.0",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-on-rails": "^11.3.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"
    }
}
```

Here is My webpack.config.js

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore   
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
    })
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })
    .enableReactPreset()
;
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

My template Twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="root"><div>
    {# {{ react_component('Entry', {'props': {'data': '', 'data2': ''} }) }} #}
    {{ react_component('KatikaChallengeMobileApp', {'props': {} }) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

the error( caused by instruction react_component) encountered is attached here.

[image: a error full full description]

Thank you one everyone who will give me a solution or track

Sincrely

Comment: Did you ever fix this? This is my second day trying to tackle this. The documentation is sparse, the example app is outdated and Google is leading me around in circles.

Comment: @Gibbo you use framework symfony + webpack + react js ?

Comment: Same issue here